# Escaping special LaTeX characters in R

Tags: r

Is there an R-function escaping special LaTeX-characters (after using `cat`).

i.e.

```
char <- "Some # special & chars ^ in \this > text"
cat(someFunction(char))
```

expected Output:
Some # special & chars ^ in $\backslash$this $>$ text

[image]

If not, any ideas about how to do it myself? All my attempts with gsub etc. failed because of escaping of "". What I've tried so far...

```
escapeLatexSpecials <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("\\", "$\\backslash$", x, fixed = T)
  x <- gsub("#", "\\\\#", x)
  x <- gsub("$", "\\\\$", x)
  x <- gsub("%", "\\\\%", x)
  x <- gsub("&", "\\\\&", x)
  x <- gsub("~", "\\\\~", x)
  x <- gsub("_", "\\\\_", x)
  x <- gsub("^", "\\\\^", x)
  x <- gsub("\\{", "\\\\{", x)
  x <- gsub("\\}", "\\\\}", x)
  x <- gsub(">", "$>$", x)
  x <- gsub("<", "$<$", x)
  return(x)
}

cat(escapeLatexSpecials("Some # special & chars ^ in \this > text"))
\^Some \# special \& chars ^ in     his $>$ text\$
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, am using something mostly similar but with `fixed=TRUE` in all the `gsub` calls.  I'm also using lualatex, so am replacing `<` with `{\\char60}` as this is the appropriate ascii/unicode code and it will stay in the correct typeface (62 is the code for `>`)

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer with an example?

Comment: At what point do you run this?

Answer (score 2):

> Found function `latexTranslate()` in package Hmisc. Seems to be what I was looking for.

-OP

```
install.packages("Hmisc"); library(Hmisc) # or alternatively, pacman::p_load(Hmisc)

latexTranslate(char) 
# [1] "Some \\# special \\& chars $^{}$ in \this $>$ text"
```

For more information, read the documentation:
https://rdrr.io/cran/Hmisc/man/latex.html